# Can the depicted function be a solution of an ODE with locally Lipschitz autonomous vector field?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

> Problem: Can x(t) depicted be a solution of a scalar differential equation x(dot)=f with locally Lipschitz autonomous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find your explanation  unsatisfactory, since  it makes no use of the Lipschitz condition (and  this condition is necessary).

The key points to emphasize:

1. Horizontal stretch means that there is an interval within which $x(t)= x_0$, a constant. This implies $f'(x_0)=0$, i.e., $x_0$ is an equilibrium point.
2. The same ODE admits the constant solution $x(t)\equiv x_0$ (its graph is horizontal line).
3. The locally Lipschitz property of $f$ implies uniqueness for IVP, which means any two solutions that agree at one moment of time have to agree always. But this contradicts the observation made in 2: the shown solution and the constant solution agree in some places and become different elsewhere.